# Loop through object within an array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I'm trying to loop through an object in an array in Laravel.

I made a `foreach` to loop through my `$request->newTags` what is an object and I just return the key. my goal is to access each `tag_name` in my `request object` what has an `array` with the multiple indexes what contain the `tag_name`.

```
foreach ($request->newTags as $tag) {
   return $tag;
 }
```

and i get my response 
[image]

how can I access each tag_name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using return on each iteration which will exit the function first ooff.But it doesnt matter because newTags only contains one item, which is an array. So it sounds like you have an object attribute $tags->newtags which is an array containing an array. I bet that this will not throw an error for example:

`echo $tags[0]["tag_name"];`

Your problem is nesting.

Comment: Yea I realized the mistake with return

Comment: Can you access your key if you go through the index of $tags? I would probably cast all to an array if $tags is mixed for simplicity btw.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I modified your answer a bit and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($request->newTags as $tag) {
   return $tag.tag_name;
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean `$tag->tag_name` ?

Comment: @Yosef Yep try that. If that doesn't work try $tag['tag_name']

Comment: both don't work doing `$tag->tag_name` will return `trying to get property of non-object` and doing `$tag['tag_name']` will return `undefined index: tag_name`

Comment: Hmm try using `pluck` https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/collections-get-only-specific-key-value

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($dates as $key => $value)
    @foreach ($humans as $human)
        {{ $human[$key]['date'] }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please explain your answer - why does it work ?