# How can I dynamiclly output the `key:value` of an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
$custom_fields = json_decode($object->custom_fields);

// output: 
"custom_fields": [
    {"foo": "bar"},
    {"something": "else"},
    {"two_words": "example"},
    {"qty": 2},
    {"comments": "Hello World!"}
]
```

I have used [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121150/loop-through-object-within-an-array-laravel) to see how I can output the values. However, in that thread the key is always the same.

What I am trying to accomplish is to populate a `textarea` with these key/values.

```
Foo: bar
Something: else
Two words: example
Qty: 2
Comments: Hello World!
```

I could hard-code these values; ideally I'd like it to be dynamic. Meaning, whatever is in the `custom_fields` array gets outputted. I may add or remove attributes in the future so not having things hard-coded is ideal.

Here's what I currently have:

```
$notes_arr = [];

foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
    $notes_arr[] = $field;
}

$notes = 'Foo: ' . $notes_arr[0]->foo . PHP_EOL;
$notes .= 'Something: ' . $notes_arr[0]->something . PHP_EOL;
$notes .= 'Two Words: ' . $notes_arr[0]->two_words . PHP_EOL;
$notes .= 'Qty: ' . $notes_arr[0]->qty . PHP_EOL;
$notes .= 'Comments: ' . $notes_arr[0]->comments . PHP_EOL;
```

Which results in this:

```
Foo: bar
Something: else
Two Words: example
Qty: 2
Comments: Hello World!
```

How can I loop through the array & output the key `Foo` and the value `bar` dynamiclly?

I will work to resolve the `two_words` into `Two words` using `str_replace` or something next.

Comment: a combination of `array_keys` and `get_object_vars`  should give a good place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that the above source data `$custom_fields` could be written like this in PHP:

```
$custom_fields=[
    (object)["foo"=>"bar"],
    (object)["something"=>"else"],
    (object)["two_words"=>"example"],
    (object)["qty"=>2],
    (object)["comments"=>"Hello World!"]
];
```

If this was `json_encode(d)` you would get:

```
[{"foo":"bar"},{"something":"else"},{"two_words":"example"},{"qty":2},{"comments":"Hello World!"}] // ie:as question source!
```

Then a combination of the `foreach` with `array_keys` and `array_values` applied to each child object, like this:

```
$notes='';
foreach( $custom_fields as $obj ){
    $key=array_keys( get_object_vars( $obj ) )[0];
    $val=array_values( get_object_vars( $obj ) )[0];
    $notes .= sprintf('%s: %s%s',$key,$val,PHP_EOL);
}
printf('<textarea cols=80 rows=5>%s</textarea>',$notes);
```

should yield:

```
<textarea cols=80 rows=5>
    foo: bar
    something: else
    two_words: example
    qty: 2
    comments: Hello World!
</textarea>
```

It should also be mentioned that one can use the second argument to `json_decode` which will force the returned output to be delivered as an associative array. With such output conventional `foreach` can be applied - where the nested objects will now be child arrays (so rather than an array of objects it is now an array of arrays )

```
$custom_fields = json_decode( $object->custom_fields, true );
$notes='';
foreach( $custom_fields as $index => $arr ){
    foreach( $arr as $key => $val )$notes .= sprintf('%s: %s%s',$key,$val,PHP_EOL);
}
printf('<textarea cols=80 rows=5>%s</textarea>',$notes);
```

Comment: Your comment to explore `array_keys` and `get_object_vars` was super helpful - exactly the push I needed—thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Php class is iterable you can try this:

```
 <?php

$array = '{"custom_fields": [
    {"foo": "bar"},
    {"something": "else"},
    {"two_words": "example"},
    {"qty": 2},
    {"comments": "Hello World!"}
]}';

   $ar = json_decode($array);

   foreach($ar->custom_fields as $key => $obj ){
     foreach($obj as $property => $val){
        echo $property."=>".$val."\t\n";
     }
   }
```

> Output:
>
> foo=>bar   
> something=>else
>      two_words=>example
>   qty=>2  
> comments=>Hello
> World!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function printLines(string $input, bool $print = true) {
    // If the first or last line is empty, trim it.
    $input = trim($input);
    $rows = explode(PHP_EOL, $input);
    foreach($rows as $index => $row) {
        $row = trim($row);
        if(empty($row)) {
            //If the line is empty, nothing to print.
            unset($rows[$index]);
            continue;
        }
        $row = explode(':', $row);
        $row[1] = $row[1] ?? '';
        $rows[$index] = $row;
        if($print) {
            echo "{$row[0]}: {$row[1]}" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    
    return array_values($rows);
}
```

**DEMO**: https://onlinephp.io/c